# Includes in multiple belongs_to association chain (avoiding N+1)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have models like below:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many: :bars
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to: :foo
  has_many: :bazs
end

class Baz < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to: :bar
end
```

How can I can includes `foo` in my `baz` query? (Something like `Baz.includes(:foo).where(condition: 'condition').map(&:foo)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to get a join to foo through the bar association. Something similar to this should work for you in `ActiveRecord`.

`Baz.joins(bar: :foo).where(foos: { SOME_FOO_COLUMN: 'condition' })`

This will return a collection of `Baz`'s where your `Foo` condition is true.

Comment: And what about case when I want to call `foo` on `baz` instance without `N+1` queries?(as in edited question)

Comment: I would recommend looking into [`ActiveRecord::QueryMethods`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html) to see what would suite you best for your query. Using `includes` can also allow you to use the included model in your queries.

You can also find some great info on [this post](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html) showing some differences between `preload`, `eager_load` and `includes`.